# How to change value inside generated HTML in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML generated with `js`:

```
var htmlBox = "<div><span class='name'></span><span class='age'></span></div>"
```

I want to display all the names from a Json object `staff` when I loop over it.

```
for(var i = 0;i <= staff.length;i++){
    $(htmlBox).find('span.name').text(staff[i]['name']); # Not sure
    $(htmlBox).find('span.age').text(staff[i]['age']); # doesn't work   

    $("#wrapper").append(htmlBox);
}
```

I dont' know exactly how to do it with *raw js* or *jquery*.

Comment: Do `$(htmlBox).find...` as-is your just working with a string.

Comment: `htmlBox` is just a string, unless you just didn't include you parsing it through jQuery

Comment: @LawrenceCherone see the edit with `$(htmlBox)`, it doesn't work.

Comment: @PatrickEvans can you show me how to have it work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest creating a jQuery object from your HTML string upon each iteration of your loop.
Also, since the array is [zero-based](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections#Understanding_length), looping until `i <= staff.length` will go one index too far.
Instead, try `i < staff.length`.

```js
var staff = [{
    'name': 'John Doe',
    'age': 100
  },
  {
    'name': 'Jane Doe',
    'age': 50
  }
];

var boxTemplate = "<div><span class='name'></span><span class='age'></span></div>";

var $wrapper = $('#wrapper');

for (var i = 0; i < staff.length; i++) {
  var $thisBox = $(boxTemplate);
  $('.name', $thisBox).text(staff[i]['name']);
  $('.age', $thisBox).text(staff[i]['age']);
  $wrapper.append($thisBox);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not storing the parsed html of your string, try this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < staff.length; i++) {
    var htmlBox = $("<div><span class='name'></span><span class='age'></span></div>");

    htmlBox.find('span.name').text(staff[i]['name']); // Not sure
    htmlBox.find('span.age').text(staff[i]['age']); // doesn't work   

    $("#wrapper").append(htmlBox);
}
```

**Also** watch out I changed the condition of your `for` loop, it was checking for `<=` and should be `<`, because in JS array indexes start from 0.

**Also also** comments in JS are with `//` for single line or `/*` and `*/` for multi line.

---

Here you have a working code snippet (with some extra stuff to make it actually work)

```js
var staff = [
  {name: 'Eu Chi', age: '??'},
  {name: 'Alvaro Castro', age: '29'}
];
for(var i = 0; i < staff.length; i++) {
  var htmlBox = $("<div><span class='name'></span><span class='age'></span></div>");

  htmlBox.find('span.name').text(staff[i]['name']); // Not sure
  htmlBox.find('span.age').text(staff[i]['age']); // doesn't work   

  $("#wrapper").append(htmlBox);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! it helps a lot

Answer (score 2):

In your example, jQuery is rebuilding your HTML after each update. Try the following:

```
var htmlBox = "<div><span class='name'></span><span class='age'></span></div>";

for(var i = 0;i <= staff.length;i++){
    var htmlJObject = $(htmlBox);
    htmlJObject.find('span.name').text(staff[i]['name']); # Not sure
    htmlJObject.find('span.age').text(staff[i]['age']); # doesn't work   

    $("#wrapper").append(htmlJObject.html());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`htmlBox` is just a string you need to parse it and then manipulate it.

Note

```
$(htmlBox).find()....
```

Will parse that string but it doesn't make `htmlBox` contain that newly created element

Instead you will need to each time you want a new element, parse it through jQuery, call find() / text(), and then append it

```
for(....){
    let box = $("<div><span class='name'></span><span class='age'></span></div>");
    box.find().text()
    $("#wrapper").append(box)
}
```

This gets you a new element each iteration that is then manipulated to what you need.

```js
staff = [
  {name:"test",age:33},
  {name:"test2",age:18},
  {name:"test3",age:56},
]

for (var i = 0; i < staff.length; i++) {
  let box = $("<div><span class='name'></span> <span class='age'></span></div>");
  box.find('span.name').text(staff[i]['name']);
  box.find('span.age').text(staff[i]['age']);

  $("#wrapper").append(box);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use append with template literal to substitute with the values from object.

```js
const staff = [{name: 'one', age: 25}, {name: 'two', age: 30}];
const htmlBox = document.createElement('div');

staff.forEach((ele) => {
  htmlBox.append(`<span class='name'>${ele.name}</span>
    <span class='age'>${ele.age}</span>`);    
});

document.getElementById('root').append(htmlBox);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate your JSON using `.each()` and append each iteration into a container.

[.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

> A generic iterator function, which can be used to seamlessly iterate over both objects and arrays. Arrays and array-like objects with a length property (such as a function's arguments object) are iterated by numeric index, from 0 to length-1. Other objects are iterated via their named properties.

```js
var data = [{
    'name': 'Micheal',
  },
  {
    'name': 'Jordan',
  }
];

$.each(data, function(i,v) {
  $('#content').append("<span class='name'>" + v.name + "</span>")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"></div>
```